# Docker error response from daemon: "Conflict ... already in use by container"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I've been using Docker on my PC to run Quantum GIS with the following instructions I've found here: [docker-qgis-desktop - A simple docker container that runs QGIS desktop](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/kartoza/qgis-desktop/)

Everything has been running fine until last week when I started to get this error message:

> ```
> Error response from daemon: Conflict. 
> The name "qgis-desktop-2-4" is already in use by container 235566ae17b8. 
> You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
> ```

I'm not entirely sure what this means despite searching for clues on this site. I hadn't changed anything prior to this happening and have been successfully launching the container with this command:

```
sudo docker run --rm --name="qgis-desktop-2-4"     -i -t     -v ${HOME}:/home/${USER}     -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix     -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY     kartoza/qgis-desktop:latest
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 368):

It looks like a container with the name `qgis-desktop-2-4` already exists in the system. You can check the output of the below command to confirm if it indeed exists:

```
$ docker ps -a
```

The last column in the above command's output is for names.

If the container exists, remove it using:

```
$ docker rm qgis-desktop-2-4
```

Or forcefully using,

```
$ docker rm -f qgis-desktop-2-4
```

And then try creating a new container.

Comment: hey @Dharmit thanks for the comment. I tried that but now get the following error message `groupadd: GID '0' already exists
useradd: user 'root' already exists
No protocol specified
Warning: qgis.bin: cannot connect to X server unix:0.0`

Comment: It seems like the image tries to make the user root, and a root group which both in fact already exists. Docker uses root:root as default user and group. But the first issue is fixed when you removed the first container.

Comment: hmm, weird so why was it working fine to begin with i.e. 3 - 4 months. Any ideas what I can do to fix this?!

Comment: How can we just restart existing container instead of killing old one and invoking with same name again?

Comment: @DhaneshMane `docker restart`, or `docker stop` & `docker start` should help you.

Comment: "The last column in the above command's output is for names." 
This is very useful. Had missed chcking and was assuming its Not there

Comment: Trying `docker-compose rm ...` Then get it... There is `docker` commands... Thank you!

Answer (score 107):

Instead of command: `docker run`

You should use:

```
docker start **CONTAINER ID**
```

because the container is already exist

[More info](https://www.edureka.co/community/10299/how-fix-this-error-docker-run-name-xyz-already-use-container)

Comment: 'docker start' doesn't give options to enable host networking, mount volumes from the command line, and other options that are necessary in my case.  So personally I had to delete (prune) then run.

Comment: @horsehair when I use docker start <myContainerName> it reestablishes all exposed ports and volume mounts.  So depending on how you initially ran your container those settings should resolve with docker start.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of sucks as I want it to work both ways....start/run for developers that join the team and for developers who ran it once before.  it's not very idempotent :(.  oh well, I guess I have to do some if logic in the bash scripts

Answer (score 52):

I got this error quite a lot, so now I do a batch removal of all unused containers at once:

```
docker container prune
```

add `-f` to force removal without prompt.

To list all unused containers (without removal):

```
docker container ls -a --filter status=exited --filter status=created
```

See [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-volumes-and-networks/) more examples how to prune other objects (networks, volumes, etc.).

Comment: `docker ps -a` list me also all the containers as @peter mortensen mentioned above.

Answer (score 17):

For people landing here from google like me and just want to build containers using multiple docker-compose files with one shared service:

Sometimes you have different projects that would share e.g. a database docker container. Only the first run should start the DB-Docker, the second should be detect that the DB is already running and skip this. To achieve such a behaviour we need the Dockers to lay in the same **network** and in the same **project**. Also the **docker container name** needs to be the same.

*1st:* Set the same network and container name in docker-compose

docker-compose in project 1:

```
version: '3'

services:
    service1:
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        # ...
        networks:
            - dockernet

    postgres:
        container_name: project_postgres
        image: postgres:10-alpine
        restart: always
        # ...
        networks:
            - dockernet

networks:
    dockernet:
```

docker-compose in project 2:

```
version: '3'

services:
    service2:
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        # ...
        networks:
            - dockernet

    postgres:
        container_name: project_postgres
        image: postgres:10-alpine
        restart: always
        # ...
        networks:
            - dockernet

networks:
    dockernet:
```

*2nd:* Set the same project using `-p` [param](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#command-options-overview-and-help) or put both files in the same directory.

`docker-compose -p {projectname} up`

Answer (score 5):

I bumped into this error while executing a `docker run` on  my splunk dev server . These steps came handy:

1. Execute :  `docker  container ls -a`
2. Get the  `containerName` from “NAMES” column, the output of step 1.
3. Execute : `docker restart <containerName>`

Answer (score 3):

The below command will resolve the issue

```
docker rm -f container_name
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31676806/2227743).

Answer (score 1):

#### Three easy solutions

(choose one)

1. Omit `--name` when starting the container (you don't *have to* name it, and if you don't, docker will just give it a random name)
2. Provide a different name (i.e. change `--name mycontainer` to `--name mycontainer2`)
3. Delete the container that already exists with that name. E.g.

```
docker container rm <container_name>
```

#### Notes

- The error occurs when you try to create a container but a container of the same name already exists
- You should be able to spot the existing one by running

```
docker ps -a | grep <container_name>
```

or just `docker ps -a` to inspect all existing containers.

Answer (score 0):

No issues with the latest kartoza/qgis-desktop

I ran

```
docker pull kartoza/qgis-desktop
```

followed by

```
docker run -it --rm --name "qgis-desktop-2-4" -v ${HOME}:/home/${USER} -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY kartoza/qgis-desktop:latest
```

I did try multiple times without the conflict error - you do have to exit the app beforehand. Also, please note the parameters do differ slightly.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was caused by using a symbolic link to that directory. So remember to use the exact path you used when creating the containers.